# How to prevent SHOW FULL TABLES query during pandas DataFrame.to_sql() call

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

`DataFrame.to_sql()` is executing the following query:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `db`
```

When using `pandas.DataFrame` with `sqlalchemy` to insert into a MariaDB database. How do I prevent this from happening?
I haven't found any references to this in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) or on SO:

```
Versions:
  Python:      3.7.4
  sqlalchemy:  1.3.4
  pandas:      1.0.3
```

To reproduce:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlalchemy as sql
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

conn = sql.create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/db')
df = DataFrame([{
  'colA': 11,
  'colB': 'this is a thing',
}])
df.to_sql('TableA', conn, index=False)
```

Output:

```
...
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO `TableA` (`colA`, `colB`) VALUES (%s, %s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:(11, 'this is a thing')
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `db`    <!-- REMOVE THIS ?
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:()
```

Comment: *"How do I prevent this from happening?"* - Why? Is it causing a problem? I just tried it with MariaDB 10.3.22 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, and thanks for your comment! We were seeing some performance issues with our DB server, and our DBA thought the query above may have been the cause. In our case, our database has >10000 tables, so the `SHOW FULL TABLES FROM \`db\`` query is returning a LOT of information, unnecessarily. However, it seems this was not the cause of our issues.